# The reinstatement of Rhodesia: avoiding a repeat of history

Tags: internal-consistency, government, politics

### Disclaimer

The below is an entirely fictional world. I'm in no way advocating for anyone to actually reinstate Rhodesia.

### Premise

In 2024, Zimbabwe has collapsed under the weight of policy impotence, hyperinflation, and infighting between the Shona and Bantu peoples. After years of civil war, central leadership was splintered and most of the bureaucrats were assassinated. In this vulnerable state, an incarnation of [Executive Outcomes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executive_Outcomes) leads a white resistance movement to reclaim approximately 50% of Zimbabwe's territory. Despite international condemnation, the tiny fraction of whites who remain in Zimbabwe flea to the neo-Rhodesia along with many of the white children and grandchildren of the original Rhodesian diaspora. One year later, the white population of neo-Rhodesia has grown to 200,000.

Though they are few in number, they have abundant access to capital abroad. This group of white Africans also has expertise in running the state. See [Niskanen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_A._Niskanen) via findings from [Keller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Keller), 1994:

> An obvious question is why the sponsor doesn't simply overrule the bureaucrat. The bureaucrat's informational advantage is critical here. A particularly striking example of the importance of information comes from South Africa. Even after the fall of apartheid, the white bureaucrats who administered the regime continued to play a predominant role in running the country. Why? The bureaucrats alone knew the secrets of running the state.

However, these bureaucrats were not perfect: many policies led to a type of plutocracy in the original Rhodesian regime. This greatly undermined social cohesion as only the whites had a capital. Enter Mugabe: he rallied rebel groups and retaliated and the rest is history. Now, the question turns to how to avoid repeating this history. Weary of previous cultural clashes, neo-Rhodesia enacts a closed-door policy: aiming to keep a homogeneous population.

The global community rejects the legitimacy of the state and has imposed sanctions (which are not so effective, as was in the original sanctions against Rhodesia). However, the economic health of neo-Rhodesia depends on integrating into the global economy to some degree. Thus, the dilemma is posed.

### Question

With the superpowers of the world eagerly watching, how can neo-Rhodesia foster legitimacy for their state given their hard stance on a closed-door policy?

**Success metric**

- Adhering to a two-state solution is preferred. Assume cultural differences cannot be reconciled, see [India Pakistan Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_India).

**Further clarifications**

- Aside from immigration, all other policy levers are in scope
- The population of neo-Rhodesia is nearly homogeneous: white Africans
- Infighting among Shona and other groups continues, but will likely unify after a few decades and may look to reclaim their lost land
- After years of civil war and mass migration, it's unclear who has been displaced; it's difficult for the global community to discern who has a legitimate claim to what.

**Notes**

- While Rhodesia did have popular support from
  powerful allies like the US in the 70s, given the shift in social
  dynamics leading to the present day, it's unclear whether support
  would remain.
- Zimbabwe had allies too, but the civil war has complicated the "concept of Zimbabwe."

Comment: Can you check your first link? It seems to be broken

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica Very odd, the markup doesn't render for that one. Tried multiple times. Will investigate further.

Comment: World Governments wouldn't tolerate a white lead mercenary initiated takeover of any country, least of all Zimbabwe. If the government collapsed into civil war the same thing would happen that always happens in such cases. Nations bordering Zimbabwe would be forced to intervene to quell the flow of refugees bringing civil disturbances with them. In this case particularly South Africa. The UN via the Security Council would also almost certainly sponsor a mandate for a multi-national military/humanitarian peace keeping mission. And both would end up being the dogs breakfast they usually are.

Comment: @Mon Not to mention if Neo-Rhodesia had a good economy you would get a huge amount of black immigration *to* Neo-Rhodesia from surrounding countries. The white government couldn't do much about them without colossal backlash. Both deporting the refugees and enforcing the borders by killing them is a humanitarian atrocity waiting to happen.

Comment: You'd also get a huge backlash from Western powers, especially the U.S. for whom a significant proportion of the population is nonwhite and the U.S. government wouldn't like a country where a significant proportion of its people aren't tolerated. Even modern ethnostates like Israel at least pay lip service to the idea of tolerating Palestinians, as least on a global scale.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it, you'd probably get an African North Korea. The West doesn't like them and neither does most of their African neighbors. India, the Middle East, and Latin America wouldn't be fond of them. South Africa might be the only African country that tolerates them (though the country is increasingly less white-dominated per year). They'd be economically isolated and living on subsistence, more or less. And of course China, Iran, and Russia would try to buddy up to them to get a political foothold.

Comment: okay, where we gather to reignite the flame? Not sure what the q does on wb as it is more political than anything else, so as it is almost impossible to answer, where are all those naysayers(closers). Those guys will need a good backer behind the curtains, and they have to be motivated and armed with local knowledge - meaning they have to be very proactive, already at way before anything happens. So there are two big variables, not unprecedented, but variables can lead to any outcome. not even talking about practical problems, and dedication to wash the land with the blood.

Comment: Fundamentally, the question is "How can a new regime be recognized as legitimate?" That recognition comes from peer states, and depends upon the *international* politics of the time far more than the *internal* politics that led to the change of regime. If "*The global community rejects [the new regime]*," then there simply cannot be "legitimacy" until the regime is changed once more...or the regime moderates their odious policies...or the international political environment shifts.

Comment: @user2352714 Not sure about that, considering the natural resources and the wealth they represent, someone would trade with them. A no-fly zone around the country could cause issues though.

Comment: @Tantalus'touch. The question is [is it worth offending and losing trade agreements with the DRC, Nigeria, Botswana, Zambia, etc.](https://www.afrikatech.com/energy/top-15-african-countries-richest-in-natural-resources/) just to buddy up to a country that is only half of IRL Zimbabwe. Probably not. China and Russia certainly would be unlikely to do it out of realpolitik if nothing else (more resources > less). Not to mention the international egg on one's face if most Western countries supported such a regime.

Comment: As long as you keep the native population downtrodden, poor, and dependent on your Elite Overlords, it will work as a system. A very unethical system, but functional. It's when you give them *some* freedom and access to weapons & independence, that they realize what they are missing and rise up in revolt. That's what happened in Rhodesia, that's what happened in India, and that's what happened in America. Too much oppression for people to be happy, but not enough to keep them in abject servitude. So either keep you underclass *really* downtrodden, or elevate them and embrace them.

Comment: @PcMan The issue OP is saying is that there *is* no black African population, the founders of Neo-Rhodesia either killed or deported them all and Neo-Rhodesia refuses to allow any into the country on ideological grounds and would sooner die than relent to pragmatism or economic motivations. The issue with this is by promoting this extreme "us versus them" narrative they've given all of the surrounding countries (except possibly South Africa) a huge motivation and casus belli to invade them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Someone needs to hoe the weeds.**

White africans will not return if they have hard agricultural labor to look forward to.  Abundant capital does not pick beans.  It hires bean pickers.

Neorhodesia is not going to be Grand Cayman and make its money off of banking and gambling.
It is agricultural land and to make a living they need to work it.  If you drove out the black people, there are not enough white Rhodesians and expats willing to do that kind of work.  The analogous situation exists in the US now - there are not enough US citizens willing to do the hard labor of agricultural work and so farmers must import guest workers from Mexico.  If your NeoRhodesia is all white and that is an important aspect of their culture, that means either you redefine "white Africans" to include persons who are willing do the work and then allow them to immigrate, or you allow in guest workers from Africa or South Asia.

As regards being accepted, the big lift is driving out all the black people who currently live in the region.  Recent history shows that Western powers are willing to intervene to stop it as they did in the Serbian war.  Or maybe not, as in the Rwandan genocide.  You can spin your story to make it what you want.  I have to think that genocidal white mercenaries driving out the population of a country would be looked on askance by most world powers.

And maybe that is OK.  Neorhodesia can be a sanctuary for right-wing white people from all over the world, and its birth in blood will make for a fine origin story.  They can easily feed themselves.  They are ostracized by the world's nations and they are fine with that.  There is money to be made from that niche too.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on how hard lined racist or pragmatic the Neo-Rhodesians would be and which parts of current Zimbabwe it occupied. The more mineral rich regions it occupied the better would be its prospects.

The European Union and more importantly, France and Germany, will oppose Neo-Rhodesia and will most likely impose sanctions.

Britain post Brexit is still to define itself globally. It once had an empire and once had influence, but it is now a small country that needs to carve out a niche for itself globally. Like the EU, it most likely will impose sanctions on Neo-Rhodesia.

India, with a population of 1.39 billion is still a developing nation with an inward focus and very independently minded. It will continue to do it own thing and will most likely not interact with Neo-Rhodesia. It still has a long memory of the racial and other transgressions committed against it during the days of the British Raj.

Seen from the outside, the USA is currently imploding. It’s a divided society were consensus between left and right is mostly impossible on most matters. It is spending more resources on managing domestic matters and less on global concerns. Globally, the USA is slowly losing its influence and is becoming less relevant. Russia and China once feared America, now they don’t.

Totalitarian countries such as Russia and China are currently in the ascendancy and are becoming increasing assertive and belligerent. They need friends.

If Russia could benefit from Neo-Rhodesia it would. If not it would condemn it.

China aspires to a high standard of living for its people, but with a population of 1.44 billion, it desperately needs resources to achieve this and to divert the nation’s attention from the failings of the ruling Communist Party. If Neo-Rhodesia and China could make a deal, and China can be very pragmatic when it wants something, while the resources are flowing from Neo-Rhodesia to China the situation for Neo-Rhodesia could be very good. Once the resources have been exploited then Neo-Rhodesia would have major problems. The mines could be operated by the Chinese using imported temporary Chinese guest labor who would be confined to mining camps.

For this to succeed, given that Neo-Rhodesia would be a land locked country, the existing transportation routes through Mozambique would need to be maintained. Failing this, a new transportation corridor would need to be established through Namibia.

The African Union and the United Nations would issue statements of condemnation, but not much else. Despite issuing statements of condemnation and raising sanctions, the rest of the world doesn’t matter.

Comment: One question would be if China/Russia supporting Neo-Rhodesia would offend the other countries they are trying to exploit or draw in as allies in Africa. They aren't going to support a country that controls a small portion of Africa if it means ruining their relationships in the rest of the continent. Exploiting 20+ countries is more useful for them than exploiting one.

Answer (score 2):

- The reinstatement of Rhodesia: avoiding a repeat of history

Then do not reinstate it, really.

Somewhat looking at Fred answer, and your premise about the impotence of local gov, and Libya whatever.

what can your New Rhodesia offer to imploding geriatrician clan oligarchy USA, failed to repeat USSR success EU, mighty communist party China, biggest country Russia?

which forces it can attract by itself, outside political forces - none.

May it be interesting for countries that have military power as means to solve their problems? Like Iran Iraq? nop - at least nothing in your answer indicates that, another satellite of geriatrician clan oligarchy USA - who needs it there - that the question u need to answer, so as what will you do with the counter reaction.

which other candidates for supporting then - different XXX organizations (u know their names) for making training resupply regroup camps - they present in Africa and active enough, but are your New Rhodesia compatible with them? and do they really get something they do not have already? But that's an option legitimization is important even Taliban get that.

Not even starting with the local situation - is it supported by locals, not whites but by black americans? and is your population ready to kill and die for <strike>Allah</strike> New Rhodesia, in the same way, those famous organizations did?

if u have nothing to offer to locals if u didn't your homework for years of shaping the opinions and more poorer they will be so more pain(jealousy whatever) it will bring to them the forming of that New Rhodesia, so easier it will be for any force to sway them against it. Any warlord will do, really, it won't suffice to defeat u but it will drain your resources, and u will become a grindstone for new forces, and in the end a stepping stone for some of those warlords. Just because it is more of them than of you, way more and they have nothing to lose.

### exchange resources for a support

- is there any btw?

do not count on it that much, Libya, Venezuela - are good enough examples - they have resources, but if it is enough to attract the interest of one force so will it be for another, and yeah in the current political landscape nothing good in that for locals.

China will mine resources at any place where it can - but they aren't money helicopter, they are profiteers as any other force which interest u may attract with your resources. As of today, there is no country in the world that does things for humanitarian reasons - everyone serves their own interests. And the money they will pay for some rights won't be too much, in a similar situation for a base they pay about 5 million a year.

No sea access and u really stuck and u have to fight your way out or negotiate with local forces.

### Changing perspective

Sure there can be some kink in external politics that may create New Rhodesia as a response to the political landscape. it is not an unprecedented situation, there are enough examples with a variety of successes, in modern time. But your people can only wait for it, and it mostly means 2 things as a result - they won't be ready when the time comes(99 percent probability), and they and the New Rhodesia - will be just a chess piece - and will it reestablish itself in a finite time when interest holds - is unpredictable and heavily depend on skills getting fishes from murky waters and the luck.

Relying on external forces is more like spinning the wheel in a casino and be a club in hands of someone else.

what needs to be done is local homework. it needs to gather local support, on basis of something that a new force can offer. And if we would be under [science-fiction](/questions/tagged/science-fiction) tag it would be time to pull some good handwavium. in reality orange revolutions show to us that handwavium is not required, but pulling the trick whites only, my guess u can dream about it but yeah it will stay only the dream. (consider my comment too, won't repeat it here)

However, if local work is done and your guys have the influence, here comes another problem - what incentive do they have, grass-roots guys to embark on that dubious endeavor. As they already have what they need. Not mentioning btw that main asset of those is the land, on which years are spend to keep it fertile, and u can't move it.

May it be speculated more, about some unknown yet force that pops up out of the clear sky and pulls the trick or helps do so. Maybe, possibilities are endless - but will they choose that New Rhodesia - yes, they may, but really not the first option on the list, and mostly if the force has some dedicated interest in the region and if it helps them to achieve their goals, but again why not to choose any existing recognized corrupt/fair/faithful gov and work with them? There are enough options already for any taste.

### Conclusion

without hard rock belief in reestablishing holy land, one like a religion, not only u can't repeat history, u can't even start. The volatility of situations, which is capable to hold such changes is long gone. And to reenable such possibility u have to know how, but nobody knows until it basically happens.

your men may offer two big fruits which worth something as of today:

- political influence, for capital development, flows
- economical rise prosperity

By may, I mean they have to have some solutions to be able to do so if they would like to claim someplace for themselves under the sun.

hmm, to sum it up - it is a dead horse Jhon, do not beat it, no use. if u ask for a price - u do not have enough money.